# Metaio SDK (AREL) - how to show image content without tracking?

Tags: arel, metaio

I have just simple rectangle button realized as image content and i wanna to show it on screen without any tracking and without using screen anchors. 
You can see i have no translation and rotation, but screen is still empty.

```
<object id="button1">
    <title><![CDATA[Button 'images']]></title>
    <assets3d>
      <model><![CDATA[html/resources/0cde94934f9b4dab0998a3d73b2865ba/0cde94934f9b4dab0998a3d73b2865ba.zip]]></model>
      <transform>
        <translation>
          <x>0.0</x>
          <y>0.0</y>
          <z>0.0000000000</z>
        </translation>
        <rotation type="eulerdeg">
          <x>0.0000000000</x>
          <y>0.0000000000</y>
          <z>0.0000000000</z>
        </rotation>
        <scale>
          <x>0.0</x>
          <y>0.0</y>
          <z>0.0</z>
        </scale>
      </transform>
      <properties>
        <coordinatesystemid>0</coordinatesystemid>
        <screenanchor flags="4">0</screenanchor>
      </properties>
    </assets3d>
    <viewparameters/>
  </object>
```

Comment: You can display the content as an html overlay using AREL

Comment: @ferdy182: i know, but i need to have it as image content

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do but you can have images on the html content and position them with css

Comment: @ferdy182: y i know, but if i need some functionality like rotation etc, i need to use image content (but i still need to show up those images like if they are placed through AREL)

Comment: you can also apply rotations etc using css. like ferdy182 said, this would be the best way to show image content. otherwise screenAnchors are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dummy-Tracking: http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/7548/explanation-on-dummy-tracking

In general the best place to ask questions about AREL or the metaio SDK is http://helpdesk.metaio.com
There you should get an answer quickly.

Comment: actually nobody there gaved me answer to this

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is here:

```
<scale>
  <x>0.0</x>
  <y>0.0</y>
  <z>0.0</z>
</scale>
```

The **0.0** is not a neutral scaling value.Your scaling transformation results in an object with no dimension. As it is shown on http://www.advancedmetaio.com/explaining-the-arel-xml-structure-part-2-transformations/, if you don't want to apply any scaling transformation your scaling values should be (1, 1, 1) :

```
<scale>
  <x>1.0</x>
  <y>1.0</y>
  <z>1.0</z>
</scale>
```